# modificar imagenes en mysql desde java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, crud, actualizacion

tengo un problema en mi proyecto a la hora de actualizar un registro en la base de datos especificamente del campo de imagen en mi formulario java, en la base de datos esta como campo Long blob.

en el computador donde realice el proyecto funciona bien, pero cuando ejecuto el .jar en otro computador no me actualiza los datos, gracias por la ayuda.

este es el codigo del boton guardar:

```
 try {
        FileInputStream archivofoto;
        PreparedStatement pps = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO planilla_hoja_de_vida (Estado,funcionalidad,ciudad,area,"
                + "tipo_equipo,marca_equipo,modelo_equipo,"
                + "nombre_equipo,no_serie_equipo,placa_inventario,modelo_cpu,serial_cpu,"
                + "procesador,velocidad_procesador,memoria_ram,"
                + "capacidad_ram,marca_disco1,capacidad_disco1,"
                + "tecnologia_disco1,marca_disco2,capacidad_disco2,"
                + "tecnologia_disco2,marca_monitor,serial_monitor,"
                + "marca_teclado,serial_teclado,marca_mouse,"
                + "serial_mouse,otro,uso_equipo,"
                + "en_red,direccion_ip,direccion_mac,"
                + "velocidad_red,descripcion_sistema,licencia_sistema,"
                + "sistemas_instalados,complementos,usuario_responsable,"
                + "ubicacion_empresa,fecha,firma_responsable,"
                + "recomendaciones,ruta,imagen)VALUE(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        pps.setString(1, estado.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pps.setString(2, funcionalidad.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pps.setString(3, combociudad.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pps.setString(4, txtarea.getText());
        pps.setString(5, comboequipo.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pps.setString(6, txtmarca_equipo.getText());
        pps.setString(7, txtmodelo_equipo.getText());
        pps.setString(8, txtnombre_equipo.getText());
        pps.setString(9, txtno_serie.getText());
        pps.setString(10, txt_placa.getText());
        pps.setString(11, txt_modelocpu.getText());
        pps.setString(12, txt_serialcpu.getText());
        pps.setString(13, txt_procesador.getText());
        pps.setString(14, txt_velocidadprocesador.getText());
        pps.setString(15, txt_memoriaram.getText());
        pps.setString(16, txt_capacidadram.getText());
        pps.setString(17, txt_marcadisco1.getText());
        pps.setString(18, txt_capacidaddisco1.getText());
        pps.setString(19, txt_tecnologiadisco1.getText());
        pps.setString(20, txt_marcadisco2.getText());
        pps.setString(21, txt_capacidaddisco2.getText());
        pps.setString(22, txt_tecnologiadisco2.getText());
        pps.setString(23, txt_marcamonitor.getText());
        pps.setString(24, txt_serialmonitor.getText());
        pps.setString(25, txt_marcateclado.getText());
        pps.setString(26, txt_serialteclado.getText());
        pps.setString(27, txt_marcamouse.getText());
        pps.setString(28, txt_serialmouse.getText());
        pps.setString(29, txt_otro.getText());
        pps.setString(30, txt_nombreequipo.getText());
        pps.setString(31, txt_enred.getText());
        pps.setString(32, txt_direccionip.getText());
        pps.setString(33, txt_direccionmac.getText());
        pps.setString(34, txt_velocidad.getText());
        pps.setString(35, txt_descripcion.getText());
        pps.setString(36, txt_licencia.getText());
        pps.setString(37, txt_sistemasinstalados.getText());
        pps.setString(38, txt_complementos.getText());
        pps.setString(39, txt_usuarioresponsable.getText());
        pps.setString(40, txt_ubicacion.getText());
        pps.setString(41, txt_fecha.getText());
        pps.setString(42, txt_firmaresponsable.getText());
        pps.setString(43, txt_recomendaciones.getText());
        pps.setString(44, txtruta.getText());
        archivofoto = new FileInputStream(txtruta.getText());
        pps.setBinaryStream(45, archivofoto);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "guardado con exito");
        pps.executeUpdate();
        limpiarcasillas();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Internal_frame_hojadevida.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ya existe placa de inventario");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Internal_frame_hojadevida.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

este es el codigo del boton cargar datos :

```
 try {
        PreparedStatement pps = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM planilla_hoja_de_vida WHERE placa_inventario=?");
        pps.setString(1, buscador.getText());
        ResultSet rs = pps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            funcionalidad.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("funcionalidad"));
            estado.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("Estado"));
            txt_placa.setText(rs.getString("placa_inventario"));
            combociudad.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("ciudad"));
            txtarea.setText(rs.getString("area"));
            comboequipo.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("tipo_equipo"));
            txtmarca_equipo.setText(rs.getString("marca_equipo"));
            txtmodelo_equipo.setText(rs.getString("modelo_equipo"));
            txtnombre_equipo.setText(rs.getString("nombre_equipo"));
            txtno_serie.setText(rs.getString("no_serie_equipo"));
            txt_modelocpu.setText(rs.getString("modelo_cpu"));
            txt_serialcpu.setText(rs.getString("serial_cpu"));
            txt_procesador.setText(rs.getString("procesador"));
            txt_velocidadprocesador.setText(rs.getString("velocidad_procesador"));
            txt_memoriaram.setText(rs.getString("memoria_ram"));
            txt_capacidadram.setText(rs.getString("capacidad_ram"));
            txt_marcadisco1.setText(rs.getString("marca_disco1"));
            txt_capacidaddisco1.setText(rs.getString("capacidad_disco1"));
            txt_tecnologiadisco1.setText(rs.getString("tecnologia_disco1"));
            txt_marcadisco2.setText(rs.getString("marca_disco2"));
            txt_capacidaddisco2.setText(rs.getString("capacidad_disco2"));
            txt_tecnologiadisco2.setText(rs.getString("tecnologia_disco2"));
            txt_marcamonitor.setText(rs.getString("marca_monitor"));
            txt_serialmonitor.setText(rs.getString("serial_monitor"));
            txt_marcateclado.setText(rs.getString("marca_teclado"));
            txt_serialteclado.setText(rs.getString("serial_teclado"));
            txt_marcamouse.setText(rs.getString("marca_mouse"));
            txt_serialmouse.setText(rs.getString("serial_mouse"));
            txt_otro.setText(rs.getString("otro"));
            txt_nombreequipo.setText(rs.getString("uso_equipo"));
            txt_enred.setText(rs.getString("en_red"));
            txt_direccionip.setText(rs.getString("direccion_ip"));
            txt_direccionmac.setText(rs.getString("direccion_mac"));
            txt_velocidad.setText(rs.getString("velocidad_red"));
            txt_descripcion.setText(rs.getString("descripcion_sistema"));
            txt_licencia.setText(rs.getString("licencia_sistema"));
            txt_sistemasinstalados.setText(rs.getString("sistemas_instalados"));
            txt_complementos.setText(rs.getString("complementos"));
            txt_usuarioresponsable.setText(rs.getString("usuario_responsable"));
            txt_ubicacion.setText(rs.getString("ubicacion_empresa"));
            txt_fecha.setText(rs.getString("fecha"));
            txt_firmaresponsable.setText(rs.getString("firma_responsable"));
            txt_recomendaciones.setText(rs.getString("recomendaciones"));
            txtruta.setText(rs.getString("ruta"));
            Image i = null;
            Blob blob = rs.getBlob("imagen");
            i = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(blob.getBinaryStream());
            Image newimg = i.getScaledInstance(370, 237, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(newimg);
            lblfoto.setIcon(image);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "no existe registro con ese numero de placa");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Internal_frame_hojadevida.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

por ultimo este el código del botón modificar:

```
try {
        FileInputStream archivofoto;
        File nombre = new File(txtruta.getText());
        archivofoto = new FileInputStream(nombre);
        PreparedStatement pps;
        pps = cn.prepareStatement("UPDATE planilla_hoja_de_vida SET estado= ?," + "funcionalidad= ?,"
                + "ciudad= ?," + "area= ?," + "tipo_equipo= ?," + "marca_equipo= ?,"
                + "modelo_equipo= ?," + "nombre_equipo= ?," + "no_serie_equipo= ?," + "placa_inventario= ?,"
                + "modelo_cpu= ?," + "serial_cpu= ?," + "procesador= ?," + "Velocidad_procesador= ?,"
                + "memoria_ram= ?," + "capacidad_ram= ?," + "marca_disco1= ?," + "capacidad_disco1= ?,"
                + "tecnologia_disco1= ?," + "marca_disco2= ?," + "capacidad_disco2= ?," + "tecnologia_disco2= ?,"
                + "marca_monitor= ?," + "serial_monitor= ?," + "marca_teclado= ?," + "serial_teclado= ?,"
                + "marca_mouse= ?," + "serial_mouse= ?," + "otro= ?," + "uso_equipo= ?,"
                + "en_red= ?," + "direccion_ip= ?," + "direccion_mac= ?," + "velocidad_red= ?,"
                + "descripcion_sistema= ?," + "licencia_sistema= ?," + "sistemas_instalados= ?," + "complementos= ?,"
                + "usuario_responsable= ?," + "ubicacion_empresa= ?," + "fecha= ?," + "firma_responsable= ?,"
                + "recomendaciones= ?," + "ruta= ?," + "imagen= ?"
                + "WHERE placa_inventario='" + txt_placa.getText() + "'");
        pps.setString(1, estado.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pps.setString(2, funcionalidad.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pps.setString(3, combociudad.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pps.setString(4, txtarea.getText());
        pps.setString(5, comboequipo.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pps.setString(6, txtmarca_equipo.getText());
        pps.setString(7, txtmodelo_equipo.getText());
        pps.setString(8, txtnombre_equipo.getText());
        pps.setString(9, txtno_serie.getText());
        pps.setString(10, txt_placa.getText());
        pps.setString(11, txt_modelocpu.getText());
        pps.setString(12, txt_serialcpu.getText());
        pps.setString(13, txt_procesador.getText());
        pps.setString(14, txt_velocidadprocesador.getText());
        pps.setString(15, txt_memoriaram.getText());
        pps.setString(16, txt_capacidadram.getText());
        pps.setString(17, txt_marcadisco1.getText());
        pps.setString(18, txt_capacidaddisco1.getText());
        pps.setString(19, txt_tecnologiadisco1.getText());
        pps.setString(20, txt_marcadisco2.getText());
        pps.setString(21, txt_capacidaddisco2.getText());
        pps.setString(22, txt_tecnologiadisco2.getText());
        pps.setString(23, txt_marcamonitor.getText());
        pps.setString(24, txt_serialmonitor.getText());
        pps.setString(25, txt_marcateclado.getText());
        pps.setString(26, txt_serialteclado.getText());
        pps.setString(27, txt_marcamouse.getText());
        pps.setString(28, txt_serialmouse.getText());
        pps.setString(29, txt_otro.getText());
        pps.setString(30, txt_nombreequipo.getText());
        pps.setString(31, txt_enred.getText());
        pps.setString(32, txt_direccionip.getText());
        pps.setString(33, txt_direccionmac.getText());
        pps.setString(34, txt_velocidad.getText());
        pps.setString(35, txt_descripcion.getText());
        pps.setString(36, txt_licencia.getText());
        pps.setString(37, txt_sistemasinstalados.getText());
        pps.setString(38, txt_complementos.getText());
        pps.setString(39, txt_usuarioresponsable.getText());
        pps.setString(40, txt_ubicacion.getText());
        pps.setString(41, txt_fecha.getText());
        pps.setString(42, txt_firmaresponsable.getText());
        pps.setString(43, txt_recomendaciones.getText());
        pps.setString(44, txtruta.getText());
        archivofoto = new FileInputStream(txtruta.getText());
        pps.setBinaryStream(45, archivofoto);
        pps.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "EL REGISTRO HA SIDO ACTUALIZADO");
        limpiarcasillas();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Internal_frame_hojadevida.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

gracias a todos los que puedan ayudarme.

este es el error que me da a la hora de hacer la modificacion:

```
    jul 06, 2020 1:39:24 PM vista.Internal_frame_hojadevida btnmodificarActionPerformed
GRAVE: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\SISTEMAS\Desktop\Sin t√≠tulo.png (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
```

entiendo que no encuentre la ruta del archivo pues estoy ejecutando el jar desde otro pc. pero no se como corregirlo pues se supone que la cargo desde la base de datos

Comment: podrias intentar que muestre algun mensaje de error dentro del catch, para cuando ejecutes el update desde el .jar en otro ordenador, validar si muestra algun error y compartirlo por aca. Saludos Gabriel G

Comment: hola, gracias por responder, @GabrielGuerrero sale esto : jul 06, 2020 1:39:24 PM vista.Internal_frame_hojadevida btnmodificarActionPerformed
GRAVE: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\SISTEMAS\Desktop\Sin t√≠tulo.png (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)